# Using ruby-git to see if local is ahead of remote

Tags: ruby, git, fetch, status

I'm attempting to find out if I can see if my local repository is ahead of my remote with ruby-git. I'm looking at https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/blob/master/lib/git/status.rb and from the looks of it this is not possible, but I could be wrong - anyone with experience with this library have any input?

I was thinking about calling fetch with the library and then shelling out to `git status | grep 'ahead'` (Or something, depending on the output of status) to see if the repository is ahead or not, but trying to do everything pure ruby if possible.

Comment: As an off-topic aside, you might checkout [grit.](https://github.com/mojombo/grit) It's a git gem that's kept a lot more up-to-date than ruby-git. Scott Chacon even even mentions this in [ruby-git's wiki.](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/wiki)

Comment: I started off using Grit actually - Can't remember why I didn't like it, but I didn't ha.